# When do Stream start publishing values to listeners?

Tags: dart, stream, reactive-programming

After reading a bunch of documentation about Streams and StreamControllers in dart I tried to build a little example and was surprised of the results. All documentation I have read states that a stream starts emiting data as soon as a listener is registered. But this doesn't show any printed data:

```
class Order
{
  String type;
  Order(this.type);
}

class Pizza
{

}



void main()
{
  Order order = Order("pzza");

  final StreamController sc = StreamController();

  sc.sink.add(order);
  sc.sink.add(order);
  sc.sink.add(new Order("pizza"));

  Stream st = sc.stream.map((order) {
    return order.type;
  })
  .map((orderType) {
    if(orderType == "pizza")
      return Pizza();
    else
      throw ("dude!, I don't know how to do that");
  });

  var sus = st.listen((pizza)
    {
      print("We did a pizza");
    },
    onError: (error)
    {
      print(error);
    });

    sus.cancel();

    sc.sink.add(new Order("pizza2"));
}
```

I was expecting this output:

```
dude!, I don't know how to do that
dude!, I don't know how to do that
We did a pizza
```

When creating streams and adding data is all "sinked" data scheduled to be emited on the next application step?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in that the documentation states that you listen on a stream to make it start generating events. However, streams are asynchronous so when you call the `listen()` method you are registering to receive events from the stream at some point in the future. Dart will then continue to run the remainder of your main function. Immediately after calling `listen()` you call `cancel()` to cancel the subscription which is why nothing is being printed.

If you remove or comment out the cancel and run it again you will see the expected output.

A slightly modified version of your code will hopefully highlight the run of events:

```
class Order {
  String type;
  Order(this.type);
}

class Pizza {}

void main() {
  print("Main starts");

  Order order = Order("pzza");

  final StreamController sc = StreamController();

  sc.sink.add(order);
  sc.sink.add(order);
  sc.sink.add(new Order("pizza"));

  Stream st = sc.stream.map((order) {
    return order.type;
  }).map((orderType) {
    if (orderType == "pizza")
      return Pizza();
    else
      throw ("dude!, I don't know how to do that");
  });

  var sus = st.listen((pizza) {
    print("We did a pizza");
  }, onError: (error) {
    print(error);
  });

  // sus.cancel();

  sc.sink.add(new Order("pizza2"));

  print("Main ends");
}
```

Running this produces the output:

```
Main starts
Main ends
dude!, I don't know how to do that
dude!, I don't know how to do that
We did a pizza
dude!, I don't know how to do that
```